# Python: finding score similarity between users within a cluster

Tags: python, python-2.7, distance, similarity, cosine-similarity

How can I calculate similarity between `user` and `score`?

For example, `df`:

```
    user    score   category_cluster
    i       4.5     category1
    j       5       category1
    k       9.5     category2
```

I want to have a result like:

similarity between `useri_j` score in the same `category_cluster` if not in the same cluster do not compute similarity. How would you measure the similarity?

Comment: You have to choose the similarity based on your application.  How did you derive 0.9 as the similarity for i and j?  Are you looking for a similarity function of some sort?

For multiple dimensions, there is a common "cosine similarity" that makes a good starting point.  However, your example is 1-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a similarity function like this, [0,1] range. Indeed, 1-dimensional, so I'm having difficulty :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to define a score function first. Among others, you have manhattan or euclidean distances, which are the probably the most used ones. For more information about distances, I suggest you looking into `scikit-learn`, they hae a wide variety of distances (metrics) implemented. Look [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html) for a list (you can research later what each of them measure).

Some of them are distance metrics (how different the elements are, the closest to 0 the more similar) while others measure similarity (like exponential kernels, closer to 1 more similar). Is easy to swap between distance and similarity metrics (being the most basic one `distance = 1. - similarity` assuming both are in the `[0,1]` range).

As for your *similarity example* `similarity[i,j] = 0.9` doesn't make any sense to me. What would be the similarity of `i and k`? Which formula did you use to get that `0.9`? If you clarify it I could provide you with a numpy based representation.

For direct similarity metrics, [have a look here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html). You can use any of them if they suit your needs. It is explained what each of those measure.

---

A example usage of `rbf_kernel`.

```
data = df['score']
similarity = rbf_kernel(data.reshape(-1, 1), gamma=1.) # Try different values of gamma
```

`gamma` here acts like a *threshold* different values of `gamma` will make *being similar* less or more *cheap*.

Comment: By `similarity[i,j] = 0.9` I meant, item i (which has score 4.5) and item j (which has score 5) are very similar in [0,1] range.

Comment: Thank you for the links!

Comment: @Silvia07 Yep, but why not `0.8` or `0.97`, how did you get that `0.9`? I would suggest something like [rbf_kernel](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#rbf-kernel), probably one of the most used similarity metrics.

Comment: it was just an example :) I removed this example. thanks, i'll look into rbf_kernel then.

Comment: @Silvia07 Oh ok, thought u  had some kind of measurement in mind, I'll edit the post with a example of how to use the `rbf_kernel`.

Comment: Thank you! It's working! :) Is it possible to normalize this similarity?

Comment: @Silvia07 it is already normalized. Most similar items (each one compared to themselves) have a score of `1`. Different values of `gamma` will give you different *normalizations* (different scores for the rest of the values).